# Are Danish shops open during Midsummer's eve?

Tags: shopping, public-holidays, denmark

I'll arrive at Copenhagen airport in on Midsummer's eve (Friday 20. June) and need to buy a tent there.

Are shops in Denmark open that day? It doesn't seem to be a national holiday, but you never know.

Also, where should I go to buy a cheap one-man tent?

Comment: This is really two questions. I'd suggest editing out the bit about where to buy a tent and ask it in a separate question.

Comment: It should be noted that in Denmark midsummer is celebrated on June 23.

Answer (score 2):

No, Midsummer's eve is not a public holiday in Denmark.

You can see a list of Danish public holidays on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_holidays_in_Denmark